# Forked-daapd with alternative soundcard

Tags: alsa, soundcard, itunes

I am trying to configure `forked-daapd` on my computer, and everything goes well except that in configuration file I can not set a new value for the line corresponding to soundcard. This is the default code in the config file:

```
#card = "default"
```

I want to use a soundcard called "DG2", which is the soundcard no.1 and has a first device that `ALSA` recognizes as no.0. So, I change the line to the following:

```
card = "hw:DG2,0"
```

I restart the daapd service and the next time I play a file through iTune remote, I get a message in my server log file saying that it can not play the file because the device is busy. Any change in the device name will return a different error, saying that the device does not exist. I am pretty sure no other uses this external device, and I don't understand why I get this message. I have tried `plughw` as well, with the same result.

When running `lsof`, I get the following result:

```
mah@HomeServer:~$ lsof /dev/snd/*
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pulseaudi 1579  mah   20u   CHR  116,3      0t0 9083 /dev/snd/controlC1
pulseaudi 1579  mah   26u   CHR 116,10      0t0 9542 /dev/snd/controlC0
pulseaudi 1579  mah   32u   CHR 116,10      0t0 9542 /dev/snd/controlC0
```

Let me add one last detail. This soundcard is just a SPDIF-out USB dongle with very limited functionality (e.g. no volume control). `Alsamixer`says it only has a PCM channel (which would be the device number 0).

Comment: The `controlC*` devices are harmless. Does `aplay -D hw:DG2 something.wav` work?

Comment: Yes, it does. No issues at all.

Comment: It works for all the following as well: `hw:DG2,0`, `hw:1`, `hw:1,0`. Also for the `plughw`s.

Comment: Then there must be some other program when `forked-daapd` is running.

Comment: Well, that is the point: really, no other program. Right when I receive an error from `daapd`, `shairport` can still successfully open the device.

Comment: And what device name is `shairport` using?

Comment: `shairport` uses the device `hw:1,0`. I have tried `hw:1,0` as well on `forked-daapd`to no avail.

Comment: When all other programs work, but not `forked-daapd`, then this sounds like a bug in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The `default` device automatically uses a plugin that can mix multiple streams together.

Try using `default:DG2` (but this will not work if the other program does not also go through `default`).

Run `lsof /dev/snd/*` to see which programs are accessing sound devices.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I added details to the question.

Does this mean that `pulseaudio`is reserving the device to itself and any other software has to pass through it to get access to the device? But isn't forked-daapd doing so? Shouldn't pulseaudio block the other applications from accessing the device as well? I open hw:0,1 with no issues on shairport.

Actually, I don't want two programs to access the card, and prefer to give exclusive access to forked-daapd. Is there any way to do so?